# Laravel: Query child using parent information

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a parent table and a child table, I was able to connect them using the `belongsTo` in the model.

```
Child Model 

public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ParentModel', 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
```

| Parent_Table | Child_Table |
| --- | --- |
| id | id |
| entity | parent_id |
|  | item_name |
|  | item_description |

What i want to do is to query my Child Table using the parent info but I can't seem to make it work

```
ChildModel::where(item.entity, '$entity')->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relationship will be

```
public function item()
{
        return $this->belongsTo(ParentModel::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

and in query use `wherehas` to check entity

```
ChildModel::with('item')->whereHas('item',function($query)use($entity){
    $query->where('entity',$entity);
})->get();
```

Comment: oh. so you need to use `with()` I tried the `whereHas`  but not with the with. thanks for this. **Cooldown for accepting the answer

Comment: @VincentDapiton without with also works but it wont return parent detail for each